# XamlParse Exception when using visual component package

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I am making a WPF application and I need it to draw some charts. I've installed DynamicDataDisplay NuGet package but I get an exception when I try to add it to xaml.
Here are some picture to help you understand:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D92W.jpg

Comment: If you remove the label, works or not?

Comment: No, then it goes up the visual tree and places the exception at something else.
But I am pretty sure it has something to do with the ChartPlotter since it compiles when I remove it

Comment: I guess you want to display some data on chart. I suggest you to use OxyPlot. You can also install as NuGetPackage

Comment: This happens with every single package I install